# Change EditTextPreference widget color in XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been having a tuff few days with the EditTextPreference object. No matter which emulator I use this on, it seems to change color slightly but always makes my text the same color as the widget itself. (Yes, I know it's not really a widget).

I can change the TEXT color and the BACKGROUND TEXT color in the XML code, but this does not help because the "CANCEL" and "OK" confirmation buttons (which are part of the widget)to tap are yellow and impossible to see on the white widget background.

Is there any way in XML to make this widget a different color? This has been very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background colour of any widget by property

```
 android:background="#ffff00"
```

enter any hex code at place of #ffff00

You can pick up hex code from   [here](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/)

you can also set a picture as a background of widget

```
 android:background="@drawable/your_image"
```

place your_image in drawable folder

Comment: I had already tried android:background but all this does is change the background where the user's added TEXT goes. It does not change the background of the widget itself.

I will try the image trick later, but I am not holding my breath.

Comment: keep background property for its parent like linear or relative layout where ever is your text.
for example if your text view is inside LinearLayout  change the background of LinearLayout

Comment: Ok thanks mate. I will try to work more on that when I get some rest. Currently passing out and every time I try to run my code now, it defaults to my old code. I even got a message warning about changes in memory different from what's on disc. Ahhhhh!  Will figure this out when I wake up.